# Como agregar titulo en la primera fila exportando excel laravel

Tags: laravel, excel, laravel-7, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

Estoy tratando de agregar en la primera fila de la exportación un titulo y en la siguiente fila mostrar los headings y la data.
Como se podria hacer eso sin usar FromView.

Estoy utilizando Maatwebsite.
algo así necesito realizar, un titulo de la exportación y las cabeceras y luego la  data

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo es

class TicketIssuedExport implements ShouldQueue, FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithMapping, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
protected $items;

```
public function __construct($items)
{
    $this->items = $items;
}
public function collection()
{
    return $this->items;
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'Nro Boleto',
        'Serie',
        'Nro',
        'Estado',
        'Núm de doc.',
   

    ];
}
```

public function map($row): array
{

```
    return [
        $row->purchaseItem->code,
        $row->purchaseItem->correlative->sequence_prefix,
        $row->purchaseItem->correlative->num_issued,
        $row->purchaseItem->getStatus($row->purchaseItem),
        $row->purchaseItem->doc_number
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: por favor coloca el codigo y la salida de tu función para poder ver que necesitas y ver si te podemos ayudar, saludos

Comment: Las imágenes de código no son bien recibidas, lee [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, agrego mi respuesta para alguien que quizas tenga el mismo problema o duda.
utilice WithEvents, para luego contabilizar cuantos headings tengo para unir las celdas y darle estilos, centrado, etc

```
public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        ['TITULO'],
        [
            'Nro Boleto',
            'Serie',
            'Nro',
            'Estado',
            'Núm de doc.'
        ]
    ];
}
  public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {

            $position_last = count($this->headings()[1]);

            $column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($position_last);
            $cells = "A1:{$column}1";
            $event->sheet->mergeCells($cells);
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cells)->getFont()->setBold(true);
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cells)->getAlignment()->setVertical(Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cells)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        }
    ];
}
```